# Prove that a DE solution does not exist after a certain time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I am unable to begin/know what do in order to show the following:

> Consider the one dimensional system
>   $$
> \dot x(t)=-\text{sgn}(x(t))=\begin{cases}
> -1 & \text{if } x(t)\ge 0 \\
> 1 & \text{if } x(t)<0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   For the initial condition $(t_0,x_0)=(0,c)$ with $c>0$, we can define the solution $\varphi(t)=c-t$ for $t\le c$. Show that there does not exist a piecewise continuous solution, however, for $t>c$.

Any help/proof would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Assume $\varphi$ exists for $t > c$. Put $\psi := - \varphi$, then $\psi$ is a solution of $x' = \text{sgn}$. Now consider the sum of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ and their derivative in $t = c$...